# elections.stackexchange.com refusing connections

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

A user in the Japanese.SE election chat pointed out today that http://elections.stackexchange.com/ isn't working.  When she clicks the link on the election page to go to that URL, she gets an error page saying:

> This webpage is not available
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

It's refusing connections for me, too.

I assume it's supposed to work.  Please make it work! :-)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what behavior is the downvote here supposed to encourage? Do people not like it when servers being down for 20+ hours is reported?  And I see the answer was downvoted, too.  Do people also dislike it when servers being down is fixed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Please make it work! :-)

Your wish is my command. With any luck I'll prevent this from happening again sometime in the next few days.